# Why is Google Analytics not tracking the viewership of my single page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up tracking for a single webpage at a location equivalent to

> https://mysubsite.mysite.com/mypage.html

What I did is create a **New Account** in GA with **Website URL** equal to the above. I got the **Tracking ID** and plopped the JavaScript as the last element of the `head` tag.

However, this is not tracking properly. There 0 Sessions, 0 Users, etc. under **Audience** -> **Overview**, whereas **Real Time** -> **Overview** does show users. That's the weird thing.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Stats can take up to 24 hours to update. Give it some time to gather data. Only the Real Time report will report data in real time, but if you are seeing data here then it means tracking is working.

Just give Google some time to get the stats together.